# Android Camera API: Way to use phone's standard button-set?

Tags: android, android-camera

so I need to modify certain properties about the way this app is taking/processing a picture.  Yet, I would like to just use the standard buttons that the android has for taking pictures, so that i don't have to code them all myself.  is this possible when doing such with a surface view and the Camera API?  like, zoom, flash, choose camera, and such

Comment: What do you mean by modifying the way it's taking the picture? You always have the option of using the built in camera app from your app.

Comment: i need to modd the image's byte array before it's saved anywhere.  is it possible to access the camera app's layout from within the camera API?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. What you can do is look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git/+/master) for it and pull the layouts and images they use from it.